# How do create an moving ocean and object foam loop without moving my object?

Tags: animation, shaders, displacement, dynamic-paint, ocean-simulation

[image]

I created an ocean simulation including bow and side foam but problem is that I can't make a very large ocean as the scene sequence requires the ship to move for a long time. Is there any way I can loop this ocean infinitely which also includes moving foam? (The black thing is the dynamic paint brush object.)